# bash: how do i cd into a directory that is written on the first line of a .txt file

Tags: bash, cd

I'm a greenhorn at bash scripting. I have a file called `dir.txt` storing this text:

```
./src/defaultPackage
```

how do I read `dir.txt` and switch to directory `./src/defaultPackage` in one line?

I've tried `cat ./dir.txt | xargs cd` but `cd` throws `no such file or directory` error

Comment: Btw.: If bash's `autocd` feature is available and enabled (`shopt -s autocd`) then `$(head -1 dir.txt)` is sufficient. This feature is only used by interactive shells.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I use the lines of a file as arguments of a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227994/how-do-i-use-the-lines-of-a-file-as-arguments-of-a-command). [What am I doing wrong in this bash function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763217/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-this-bash-function) is also related although the title is really vague.

Comment: `xargs cd` will not be useful in any context, because `xargs` is for running external commands and `cd` is a shell builtin. It is not `cd` throwing `no such file or directory`, but `xargs` throwing that error, because it cannot find any command called `cd`.

Answer (score 5):

You could do

```
 cd "$(head -1 dir.txt)"
```

for explanations, read the [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html) manual then [head(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html). In some cases (e.g. if `dir.txt` contains comments) you may want to use [gawk(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html) instead of `head`.

Notice that [xargs(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) cannot work with any [bash-builtins(7)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/bash-builtins.7.html), including `cd`; `xargs` needs an [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) file (or script) since it uses [exec(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) functions. See [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html).

You may want to read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) then study the source code of your [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), which is [*free software*](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). You could be interested in using [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) or [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) or [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) to understand the behavior of programs or [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), including your [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell).

Of course, avoid weird characters such as newlines, tabs, or spaces in file or directory names. See [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) and [glob(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

You could consider using [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) (see [this](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/guile-tutorial-1.html) and [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html)) or [Python](https://python.org/) for your scripts. Both are much more readable (and in my opinion, easier to write) than `bash` or even [zsh](https://zsh.org/) or [fish](https://fishshell.com/). Of course, use a [distributed version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control) system (such as [git](https://git-scm.com/) or [mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/)) on your scripts.

You might be interested by [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/).

Comment: Why would it be one? Bear in mind that I am not a native English speaker

Answer (score 0):

Using only builtins:

```
IFS= read -r line < dir.txt
cd -- "$line"
```

To read a line from a file, use `read` (and not `head`/`cat`/`sed`/whatever).

The reason you get your error, is that `cd` is a builtin, and not a command in your `PATH`: it wouldn't make sense for `cd` to be an external command, and it changes the internal state of the shell.

Note that if the line is empty, this will `cd` to `$HOME`. To avoid that:

```
IFS= read -r line < dir.txt && cd -- "${line:-.}"
```